# AWS Iot authentication error using with Open Id Connectivity

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, openid-connect, aws-iot

AWS IOT connection from the federated login(in cognito Identity) was unsuccessful

1. In cognito user pool i set up and identity provider with Microsoft account as OIDC and login with microsoft office credentials.
2. by exchanging the code generated from the Microsoft I am able to get the access token, refresh token and Id token from the cognito token end point.
3. By exchanging the id token with with aws.config.credentials i am successfully retrieving the access key id, secret key and session token.
4. I am trying to connect with the AWS iot endpoint by providing the access key id, secret key and session token.
5. The connection was unsuccessful to websocket and throwing the below error.

   > 2019-04-29 14:48:12.006 TRACEID:420de021-715b-d81d-4a5e-daedde37dfd4 PRINCIPALID:AROAIN6B4B4KMSI2U3UEY:CognitoIdentityCredentials [ERROR] EVENT:MQTT Client Connect MESSAGE:Connect Status: AUTHORIZATION_ERROR Failure reason:AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE

> NOTE: With cognito user the connection was successful

'''

```
function connectWSHandler(dispatch){  

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var AWSIoTData = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

var AWSConfiguration = {
poolId: 'us-east-1:*****************************', 
host:"a************-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
region:  'us-east-1'
};

var wsOptions = {
handshakeTimeout:15000,
rejectUnauthorized:false
}

var clientId =  localStorage.getItem("IdentityId"); 

var accessKeyId = localStorage.getItem("AccessKeyId");
 console.log('accessKeyId',accessKeyId);
 var secretKey = localStorage.getItem("SecretKey");
 var sessionToken = localStorage.getItem("SessionToken");

 if(accessKeyId==null || secretKey==null || sessionToken==null)return;

 mqttClient = AWSIoTData.device({
 host:AWSConfiguration.host,
 clientId: clientId,
 protocol: 'wss',
 websocketOptions:wsOptions,

 maximumReconnectTimeMs: 8000,
 debug: true,

 accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
 secretKey: secretKey,
 sessionToken: sessionToken
  });
```

The connection to the AWS IOT should successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the above problem by attaching the iot policy to the client id which we are using to connect.
**NOTE:client id is nothing but the identity id of user**

```
 //Need aws-sdk.js to work
      function attachPrincipalPolicy(policyName, clientid) {
          new AWS.Iot().attachPrincipalPolicy({ policyName: policyName, principal: clientid}, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                    console.error(err); // an error occurred
                }
          });
       }
```

The iot policy was to be created in the AWS IOT CORE to connect and publish